# My product images are 500px but eBay export still complains image is <500px

Tags: magento-1.7, product-images, ebay

I've done A Horrible Thing and bulk resized all images less that 500px up to a minimum of 500px by doing this:

```
find -type d \( -path ./cache -o -path ./placeholder \) -prune -o  -type f -regextype posix-egrep -iregex '.*\.(jpg|gif|tif)$' -exec identify {} \; | awk '{ split($3, wh, /x/); } wh[1] < 500 && wh[2] < 500 { print $1; }'  | while read i; do convert $i -resize 500 -quality 90 $i ; done
```

I've then deleted the 100x100 resized images with:

```
find ./ -name "resized*" -exec rm {} \;
```

That worked perfectly on the filesystem.
I delete the Magento image cache (confirmed at filesystem level)

Unfortunately when I try running M2EPro to revise the eBay listings, it receives an error back that the image is < 500px.

If I take the raw image and re-save it using the Magento Admin it will be accepted and revised correctly without error.

**My question is does Magento somehow store or cache the image dimensions somewhere on upload?** How can I flush or get Magento to recalculate this for all images?

Comment: it probably cached the image url -- check it out. that may be the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've realised it's due to eBay caching the image URL with my 30 day expire Cache-Control from NGinx.

Answer (score 0):

Magento never does that thing.

It just keep the product images inside `media/catalog/product/` directory, whenever the image is shown on frontend with resized by using `catalog/image` helper class method resize($width,$height), the product image is resized and cached into `media/catalog/product/cache`.

Comment: That's what I thought, thanks for confirming.
I'm not sure where to go from here.